# SF Tag merge- tape and tapedrive?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

On ServerFault, there are tags [tape] and [tapedrive].  [tape] has 40 questions, [tapedrive] has 3. It seems that [tape] is being used for all aspects of tape backup, including questions specific to drives, and one of the [tapedrive] questions should really be under [tape].

Do you think it's worthwhile to have two tags?  I think only [tape] is necessary, but I also see the argument that some of the existing [tape] questions which discuss tape drives should have [tapedrive] added to them.

Answer (score 3):

I agree. I reviewed all three "tapedrive" questions and added the "tape" tag. In one case I removed the "tape-drive" tag.